# Print without Header and Footer using Microsoft XPS Printer

Tags: xps

Is there any way to print a webpage or image in Microsoft XPS Printer without a header and footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all programs have a **Print setup** or **Page Setup** to enable/disable headers and footers.

In Chrome go to Print and uncheck headers and footers.

**Set everything to blank.**

Here is the IE way:

[image: IE enter image description here]
Here is firefox way

[image: FF Page setup dialog]